# Is there a way to keep my local IP the same?

Tags: networking

Every time I restart my Laptop it changes my  LOCAL IP from 192.168.1.102 to 192.168.1.105 or some other random number.

Is there a option for it to recognize my MAC and keep my local IP the same, I have to keep changing the opened ports for my port forwarding each restart.

( I don't need a static Public IP, I just need a static IP for my router to allow me to play games, or host websites ect.)

Comment: This should be an option of your internet / router box.

Comment: @j0k This doesn't have to do with the router which is assigning IP's with DHCP. He's asking about manually configuring the IP of his laptop. Though most routers do recognize your mac address and don't give away your IP that quickly.

Comment: @Anagio well depends on the box. On my box I can associate a MAC address to a local IP. So, the machine will always has the same **local IP** -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/XLbpH.png

Comment: @j0k what type of router do you have?

Comment: @Anagio I have a Linksys E3200. so I'm not sure how this helps my local IP not my public IP (eg 173.XXX.XXX.XXX)

Comment: @Loper324 my comment was directed towards jOk.... Have you checked my answer on how to set your IP manually below?

Comment: @Loper324 you may want to ask this question on serverfault which has more people familiar with networking. Just saw this was closed.

Comment: @Anagio I'm using the one provided by my ISP (which is [Free](http://www.free.fr/adsl/freebox-revolution.html)).

Comment: @Anagio It's better suited to superuser.com, and is already covered under various angles: http://superuser.com/search?q=static+ip

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty lengthy article on how to set your IP on Windows XP, Vista, and 7. You'll need to set your IP and default gateway. DNS you can leave to pickup automatically.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

Keep in mind if you take your laptop to another location with wifi for example you'll have to disable the static IP in your laptop and go back to DHCP. It takes a few seconds though to switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual address rather than using DHCP. The workflow depends on which operating system you are on. Linux and Mac you can use DHCP for other setting and manual address for IP number. I don't know about Windows, but I'm sure you can use manual address for windows to.

In Mac and Linux, just open your network setting and in Mac select use DHCP and manual addressing. In Linux network manager just enter your desired IP address.